# How to use the variable in one action to another action

Tags: ruby

In the ruby controller, I have two methods in the same controller.

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

def first
  variable_one = xxxx
end

def second
// do something
end

end
```

I want to use the variable one in the method first, and use it in the method two. I tried to assign the variable one to a session hash. `session[:variable_one] = variable_one`, and access it in the method two. But it turns out the session[:variable_one] in the method two is nil. These two methods don't have the corresponding views, so I cannot add a link_to and pass parameters. The method one cannot be set as before_action as well.

Could you please have some suggestions on this problem? Thanks so much.

Comment: So, are these both controller actions? Like the client first hits the endpoint for `first` and then hits the endpoint for `second`? The `session` approach should work in that case, but you have to make sure the endpoints are being called in the correct order.

Comment: @maxpleaner Yes, they are both controller actions. The client did hit the endpoint ```first```. The endpoint ```first``` is to send a sms to a user, and the endpoint ```second``` is hit through the received sms (through Twilio) from the user. I want to update my data through the response of user in ```second```.  However, the data in the first method cannot retrieved in second method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that `session` is stored via cookie, and therefore it is specific to one *device*. So, you will have one `session` between the rails app and your frontend, and another `session` betweeen the rails app and *Twilio* (probably the Twilio session will reset between each request). Basically, they're totally separate contexts.

Possibly you could figure out how to pass the information along via Twilio - see https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications - but as a general-purpose workaround, you could just store the column on the database.

First, make a migration to add the column:

```
add_column :users, :my_variable, :string
```

Set this value in the first endpoint:

```
def first
  current_user.update my_variable: "xxxx"
end
```

Then read it from the second:

```
def second
  # first you would need to load the user, then you can read the value:
  my_variable = current_user.my_variable

  # you could set the db value to nil here if you wanted
  current_user.update my_varible: nil
end
```

Comment: The problem is when the program receive message from Twilio, it cannot retrieve current_user. I setup the current_user method in my application controller. When the message received, the current_user is a NilClass

Comment: @Sheila ok, this is really more a question about how to use Twilio's API then. Maybe you should post a new question showing your actual Twilio-related code, since it is very much relevant here.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. I just post a new question. Hope it works.